# Select max from a List using Generics

Tags: java, list, generics, max, option-type

I have to write a method which selects the maximum value from a list, and it has to be with Generics. Obviously the List can be Number and String as well. (The return value has to be Opt Object. This is the tasks.)

This is what I have so far, but its not working, I would appreciate your advice:

```
public static <T> Opt<T> max(List<? extends Object> list) {
    T max = (T) list;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i) > max) {
            max = (T) list.get(i);
        }
    }
    return (Opt<T>) max;
}
```

And this is the main looks like: (From this one I have to make my method work.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
   
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    Utility.addTo(stringList, "aghi");
    Utility.addTo(stringList, "fed");
    Utility.addTo(stringList, "ghh");
    Utility.addTo(stringList, "abc");
    Utility.addTo(stringList, "123");
    System.out.println("The maximum value: " + Utility.max(stringList).get());

List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
    Utility.addTo(intList, 123);
    Utility.addTo(intList, 456);
    Utility.addTo(intList, -199);
    Utility.addTo(intList, -90);
    Utility.addTo(intList, 0);
    Utility.addTo(intList, -10);
    Utility.addTo(intList, 200);
    System.out.println("The maximum value: " + Utility.max(intList).get());

List<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<>();
    Utility.addTo(doubleList, 123.0);
    Utility.addTo(doubleList, 456.001);
    Utility.addTo(doubleList, -199.0);
    Utility.addTo(doubleList, -90.90);
    Utility.addTo(doubleList, 0.0);
    Utility.addTo(doubleList, -10.20);
    Utility.addTo(doubleList, 200.1);
    System.out.println("The maximum value: " + Utility.max(doubleList).get());
}
```

And the Output shoud be:

```
The maximum value: ghh
The maximum value: 456
The maximum value: 456.001
```

Comment: Which error are you getting that you don't understand?

Comment: Please be more specific with the question. Which part is not working?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection,java.util.Comparator)

Comment: 1. Is `Opt` a type you have to create or a misspelled version of `Optional`? 2. You can not declare a parameter `List<? extends Object> list` (a list of arbitrary things) and promise to return an `Opt<T>` (an optional value of a *specific* type). You should use a parameter `List<T> list` to declare that the type of the list elements must correspond to the return type. Then, you don’t need those `(T)` type casts. Further, you can’t create an `Opt<T>` by just casting the `T` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working (I mean cannot be compiled) because of this line:

```java
if (list.get(i) > max) {
```

In Java, there are no [overloaded operators as in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), so you need to find another way...

By `Opt` you probably meant `java.util.Optional` class and you can use it like this:

```java
    public static <T> Optional<T> max(List<T> list) {
        Optional<T> max = Optional.empty();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
//            if (list.get(i) > max) {
                max = Optional.of(list.get(i));
//            }
        }
        return max;
    }
```

This is of course not working, it returns last element from list.

When creator of a class expects users might be interested in sorting (comparing), they would implemente `java.lang.Comparable`, this is the case for `String`, `Long` and `Double`. So instead of T, you can say `T extends Comparable` like this:

```java
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Optional<T> max(List<T> list) {
        T max = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            final T item = list.get(i);
            if (max == null) {
                max = item;
            } else if (max.compareTo(item) < 0) {
                max = item;
            }
        }
        if (max == null) return Optional.empty();
        return Optional.of(max);
    }
```

Look at [Comparable#compareTo JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-).

Try to understand what this line means exactly (and why you cannot use it with list of `java.lang.Object`s):

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Optional<T> max(List<T> list) {
```

and why we do not need it in addTo:

```java
public static <T> void addTo(List<T> list, T e) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Streams makes it really easy by doing all the work for you:

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Optional<T> max(List<T> list) {
    return list.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder());
}
```

or the `Collections` class of utility functions:

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Optional<T> max(List<T> list) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return Optional.empty();
    } else {
        return Optional.of(Collections.max(list, Comparator.naturalOrder()));
    }
}
```